# Sidekiq enqueueing jobs, not dequeueing them

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, redis, sidekiq

For some reason, Sidekiq isn't running any jobs for me. It can enqueue them perfectly fine, but it never moves them off the queue.

I've confirmed that redis is running:

```
ps aux | grep redis
root      2756  0.0  0.0 140612  2656 ?        Sl   Sep03   0:36 redis-server *:6379
root      7489  0.0  0.0 110284   840 pts/0    S+   09:19   0:00 grep redis
```

I've confirmed that Sidekiq is running:

```
ps aux | grep sidekiq
root      6732  0.1  1.9 2527436 148000 ?      Sl   09:04   0:03 sidekiq 3.2.1 CompleteSet-Rails [0 of 25 busy]                                                                                              
root      7901  0.0  0.0 110280   840 pts/0    S+   09:44   0:00 grep sidekiq
```

I started Sidekiq using:

```
bundle exec sidekiq -d -e production -L log/sidekiq.log
```

I've confirmed that it is adding jobs to the queue:

```
Sidekiq.redis { |r| r.lrange "queue:default", 0, -1 }.length
=> 70 
UserMailer.delay.reset_password(User.third)
=> "9fc420a5b21224e5b264b9e9" 
Sidekiq.redis { |r| r.lrange "queue:default", 0, -1 }.length
=> 71
```

I'm not using custom worker classes, and I'm not trying to use a custom .yml or .rb config file. Any ideas why it's not executing jobs?

EDIT:

I did notice that options doesn't return any queues. Could that have something to do with it?

```
Sidekiq.options
=> {:queues=>[], :labels=>[], :concurrency=>25, :require=>".", :environment=>nil, :timeout=>8, :error_handlers=>[], :lifecycle_events=>{:startup=>[], :quiet=>[], :shutdown=>[]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't explicitly set it to check log/sidekiq.yml, or config/initializers/sidekiq.rb, but it was checking them anyway. In the initializer file, I had it set to only read from a queue called production, but because I was using `Mailer.delay.whatever`, it was writing to the default queue, even though I had it configured to use production only. If you want to change which queue you write to, either use a custom worker, or use `Mailer.delay(queue: name)` to put it on the queue you want.